# Python - Sorting Lists - Functions

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, lambda

The below code sorts the strings in the ex_lst list by their second letter and puts them in a new list (sorted_by_second_let)

```
ex_lst = ['London', 'Manchester', 'Newcastle', 'Southampton', 'Bristol', 'Glasgow']
sorted_by_second_let=sorted(ex_lst,key=lambda word:word[1])
print(sorted_by_second_let)
```

How can we do the same thing using a function instead of a lambda?

Thank you!

Comment: Define a custom function which returns the second letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom function which returns second letter, though simpler function would better be a `lambda`:

```
def second(word):
    return word[1]
sorted_by_second_let = sorted(ex_lst, key=second)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort_by_second_letter(lst):
    new_lst = {}
    for word in lst:
        new_lst.update({word[1]: word})
     return sorted(new_lst)
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants. This returns a sorted list of letters.

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you please execute OP's code? He wants the same output using function instead of `lambda`.